# Unable to locate USB debugging option

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, developer-options

I have reset my samsung galaxy note 3 to the factory!
Currently, the android is 5.0 and I am not able to locate developer options to enable the USB debugging information. Any idea?

Model Number: SM-N900

Android Version: 5.0

Build Number: LRX21V.N900XXUEBOL2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click on "About Device", then press on the *Build Number* field 7 times to display *Developer Options* where you would enable *USB Debugging*.